# How to ALTER a single attribute of a column?

Tags: mysql, ddl

If you're writing a data migration script and want to change some aspect of a column, the typical (and seemingly only) way is to write an `ALTER TABLE CHANGE COLUMN ...` statement. However this requires you to re-state the entire column definition.

We've had some versioning issues with this in the past. To illustrate, let's say we have this pre-existing table:

```
CREATE TABLE Book (id INT, type VARCHAR(25) DEFAULT 'Hardcover');
```

One problem is where somebody writes a migration but changes one aspect of a field but forgets to re-declare all attributes, like this:

```
ALTER TABLE Book CHANGE COLUMN type type VARCHAR(30);
-- Opps, just deleted the DEFAULT 'Hardcover' attribute
```

There's also been the case, where two migrations clobber each other like this:

```
-- Bob and Joe both get the latest db schema
-- Joe checks in this migration to increase the char length from 25 to 50:
ALTER TABLE CHANGE COLUMN type type VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT 'Hardcover';
-- Without noticing Joe's change, Bob checks in this migration to add NOT NULL:
ALTER TABLE CHANGE COLUMN type type VARCHAR(25) DEFAULT 'Hardcover' NOT NULL; 
-- Opps, Bob just clobberd Joe's change of char length
```

What would be ideal is if there was a way to modify just a single attribute of a field such as it's data type, nullability, default value, charset, etc without re-declaring everything at once. This would alleviate both of the above problems in most cases.

I'm thinking either:

1. Is there a syntax for just modifying one aspect/attribute of a column? or ...
2. Is there a way in SQL itself to read the column definition, modify one aspect then re-declare it?

Comment: Yeah I'm not saying Bob's change was inherently wrong. I'm just saying that in some cases, the effect of these types of changes aren't what was intended. Narrowing the change would reduce or eliminate that.

Comment: @KenWhite I think what OP would like to have, is syntax like `ALTER TABLE CHANGE COLUMN type CHANGE type VARCHAR(25) TO VARCHAR(50)` and `ALTER TABLE CHANGE COLUMN type ADD CONSTRAINT NOT NULL`, which sure sounds reasonable. I find myself often checking for existence of a column before adding or changing it. What I'd like to see (and possibly OP as well) is a way of specifying "I don't care what it looks like _now_, this is what I want it to look like when I'm done." Sort of a `MERGE` statement for DDL, if you will.

Comment: @KenWhite I'm not trying to make an argument that the current ALTER TABLE syntax is flawed. I understand the need to be able to take away an attribute. But as SQB says, I'm asking if there's a way to alter just one attribute - obviously it would require a different syntax to prevent ambiguity with the case you're talking about. If there was a native SQL way to do this I suspect somebody would have already pointed it out though.

Comment: @SQB and Marplesoft: Thanks for clarifying the question. I understand now what's being asked here. (I'll clean up my comments to remove the clutter.) I don't know of any of the major DBMS that support that either.